# How to add 2 binary in list form together in python

Tags: python

i want to check whether the sum of 2 binary list equals to another binary list

```py
[1, 0, 1] + [0, 1, 1] == [1, 1, 1]
```

how do i go about doing that in python? tried using numpy but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first question. You say numpy doesn't work, but what exactly have you tried? Add your complete code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful for you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What do you mean, 'binary list'? Is your statement expected to be false?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert decimal to binary using function `bin()`:

```
num1 = 2
num2 = 3

res = bin(num1 + num2)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
list(map(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 0, 1] , [0, 1, 1]))==[1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try to do something like that:

```
result = bin([1, 0, 1] + [0, 1, 1])
print([1, 1, 1] == result)
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`